# Computing $i\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \sin(e^{4e^{i\theta}}) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I wanted to calculate:

> $$\int\limits_{|z|=4} \frac{\sin(e^z)}{z} dz$$

Using the Cauchy integral form, it's easy to check that:

> $$=\int\limits_{|z|=4} \frac{\sin e^z}{z-(0)} = 2\pi i \sin(e^0) = 2\pi i \sin(1) $$

But... then I thought, what if I compute the contour integral *directly*, without the use of Cauchy's theorem?
Evaluating the parametrization $z=4e^{i\theta}$:

> $$
> \begin{split}
> &=\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin\big(e^{4e^{i\theta}}\big)}{4e^{i\theta}} 4ie^{i\theta}d\theta\\
> &=i\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \sin\big(e^{4e^{i\theta}}\big) d\theta
> \end{split}
> $$

and from there I'm stuck.

Any hint on the integral will be appreciated <3.

Comment: What does $\dfrac{\sin(e^z)}z$ have to do with $\dfrac{e^z}{z+1}$? That said, I don't believe you (or anyone else) are going to evaluate that parametric integral directly.

Comment: This is the big advantage of Cauchy integral formula, it helps us with integrals which are too hard to calculate in a direct way. So why would you try other ways?

Comment: Oops... that was a typo, thanks!. So, in summary, both of you think that there's no point on trying to evaluate the integral directly, right?. Thanks again for your time